# wpdb update multiple row?

Tags: query, wpdb

I need to change the meta value of all users at once. Seem there are no api for this,except using custom database query.

This is my code:

```
$matches = array('meta_key' => 'user_token');
$data = array('meta_value' => '100');
$wpdb->update( "$wpdb->usermeta", $data, $matches);
```

The problem is this only update one user meta value, not all users meta value with the meta key of 'user_token'.
Does $wpdb->update  limited to update single row only? Or I did something wrong?

Comment: The original code works for me, that is, it updates multiple rows at a time. But I made sure to declare the global $wpdb before the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code of wpdb method is correct.
posible reasons why it fails...

1. you have only one user that match's meta_key = 'user_token'
2. other functionality change query at **query** hook filter strage.

debug the final SQL with

```
add_filter( 'query', 'query_report', 10000 );
function query_report($sql){ 
    var_dump($sql); 
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: I think I found the problem, SQL result cache is the case. Because I was looking directly to the database. I keep refreshing the database while the database not ready to perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are different ways for **UPDATE**:

1)

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
global $wpdb;

$matches = array('meta_key' => 'user_token');
$data = array('meta_value' => '100');
$wpdb->update( "$wpdb->usermeta", $data, $matches);
?>
```

2)

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
global $wpdb;

$multi=array('34','55');
Foreach ($multi as $each){
  $result = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta SET meta_value = '111' WHERE post_id = '$each'", "blahblah" ) ); var_dump($result);
  //OR update_post_meta($each, 'meta_key_NAME', 'YOUR_VALUE' );
  }
?>
```